# How can I add the Latex on python path?

Tags: installing, python, matplotlib

I'm using Cent OS i386. I got a error message when I use `matplotlib` python package.

```
RuntimeError: LaTeX was not able to process the following string: 'lp'
```

So, I did `yum install tetex`. but it still has error.

It seems to I must add the path of LaTeX on python. But, I don't know where is LaTeX directory and which one is added to Python `PATH`.

Thank you for reading this.

Comment: Install this: `yum install texlive-type1cm`. I believe you are missing this package. Or just ensure this it is already installed.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: @m0nhawk Thanks for Comment. But this is call back to me..'No package texlive-type1cm available.'
'Error: Nothing to do'

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem. The `PATH` variable that is set in my shell is correct and included my custom `bin` dirs, including Latex. However the one "seen" by Python doesn't. Here is what I'm using:

```
import os
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + '/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-darwin'
print(os.getenv("PATH"))
```